# How to read multiple PDF files in R?

Tags: r, pdf

I have a script that I am using to read multiple PDF files. Here is my code

```
corpus_raw <- data.frame("company" = c(),"text" = c(), check.names = FALSE)

for (i in 1:length(pdf_list)){
  print(i)
  document_text <- pdf_text(paste("V:/CodingProject2_FundOverview/", pdf_list[i],sep = "")) %>% 
    strsplit("\r\n") 

  document <- data.frame("company" = gsub(x = pdf_list[i],pattern = ".pdf", replacement = ""), 
              "text" = document_text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE)

  colnames(document) <- c("company", "text")
  corpus_raw <- rbind(corpus_raw,document) 
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 79, 56
```

I even tried to keep the `check.names = FALSE` but it seems like I am doing something wrong. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I knew I was doing something stupid. Anyways, I was able to figure out the answer on my own.

```
for (i in 1:length(pdf_list)){
  print(i)
  document_text <- pdf_text(paste("V:/CodingProject2_FundOverview/", pdf_list[i],sep = "")) %>% 
    strsplit("\r\n") 

  document <- data.frame("company" = gsub(x = pdf_list[i],pattern = ".pdf", replacement = ""), 
              "text" = I(document_text), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE)

  colnames(document) <- c("company", "text")
  corpus_raw <- rbind(corpus_raw,document) 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in words what you did to solve your problem?